# What is the beginning dot notation in c#?

Tags: c#

I came across a tutorial on Full Stack .Net Web Development and I've never seen the use of the dot operator is this way for C# as of yet.  Can someone explain what it means in regards to why don't the statements end in semicolons and also do the statements belong to a specific object?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They've just added whitespace where whitespace is allowed. It's exactly the same as `new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel().UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())....` all written on one line.

Comment: One semi-colon is missing after `.Build()` though

Comment: @Heinzi This is not actually a duplicate. The linked question is about terminology, this one is about valid syntaxes and whitespace, even though both refer to similar pieces of code.

Comment: @Alejandro: Actually, the question doesn't really mention whitespace at all, but I agree that it could be seen as different. The question is: Is it different enough? Is it beneficial to future readers to have this as a separate (non-dupe-linked) question with separate answers?

Comment: @Heinzi Well, no, the answer is all about whitespace, the question could be improved to something like "Why is this valid syntax?", while the linked is about using chained methods, and this one is about C# syntax, in particular to chained methods, but can also apply to more situations (not stated here). If you look at all the answers in the link, no one uses this exact syntax and they don't explain why it's valid C#, just how methods are called one after another. This one is about source code, the other is about execution and design, which make me think that it's worty to have both of them.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks because its still not clear to me as to why towards the end there is a method called Run which begins with calling the host object however the other methods don't.  I'm not 100% sure if the other methods are a part of the object called host.

Comment: @Alejandro: OK, I have reopened the question. Feel free to write an answer. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply a single statement split across multiple lines, and also an example of fluent method chaining.

Each method call returns an object, which then can be de-referenced to perform another method call.

Here's a simple-ish example to give you an idea of how it works.  Note how each method returns the current instance of `Person`, i.e. `this`.

```
class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public decimal HeightCm { get; set; }

    public Person WithName(string firstname, string surname)
    {
        Firstname = firstname;
        Surname = surname;
        return this;
    }

    public Person BornOn(DateTime date)
    {
        DateOfBirth = date;
        return this;
    }

    public Person WithHeight(decimal heightCm)
    {
        HeightCm = heightCm;        
        return this;
    }
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
var person = new Person().WithName("Doctor", "Jones").BornOn(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1)).WithHeight(175);
```

Which can also be expressed as:

```
var person = new Person()
    .WithName("Doctor", "Jones")
    .BornOn(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1))
    .WithHeight(175);
```

Splitting it across multiple lines is not necessary, but could either be a stylistic choice, or dictated by your coding standards.

Comment: The revision to the first sentence is perfect +10

Comment: @mason, I see.  I didn't intend to define fluent method chaining in that manner, but can see how it could be interpreted that way.  I've now amended my answer, please let me know if you thing that's an improvement.

Comment: Yep, looks much better.